# Re-render the component with new data without having local state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-thunk

I'm practicing react and redux and I'm creating a simple app where I have a sidebar showing a list of categories that is visible on every route and the main area that initially displays all the books I have and when clicking on a category link on the sidebar the main area loading another component  with all the books related to this category.

Here's my routes setup in the `App.js` file ...

```
class App extends Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            await this.props.asyncLoadBooks();
            await this.props.asyncLoadCategories();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Header />
                <div className="global-wrapper">
                    <div className="container">
                        <aside className="side-bar">
                            <Categories />
                        </aside>

                        <main className="main-content">
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path="/" component={Books} />
                                <Route
                                    exact
                                    path="/category/:id"
                                    component={Category}
                                />
                                <Route component={NotFound} />
                            </Switch>
                        </main>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

In the `App.js` as you can see I'm loading the data via a local JSON file with axios in the `Actions` files of the `booksActions` and `categoriesAction`, it's pretty straightforward.

And here's the Categories component ...

```
class Categories extends Component {
    render() {
        const { categories } = this.props;

        let categoriesList;

        if (categories && categories.length !== 0) {
            categoriesList = categories.map(category => (
                <li key={category.id}>
                    <Link to={`/category/${category.id}`}>{category.name}</Link>
                </li>
            ));
        } else {
            categoriesList = <Loading />;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Categories</h2>
                <ul>{categoriesList}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapState = state => ({
    categories: state.categories.categories
});

export default connect(mapState)(Categories);
```

And I'm firing another action in the `ComponentDidMount()` of the single Category component to get all the books related to that component and render them ...

```
class Category extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getCategoryBooks(this.props.match.params.id);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
            this.props.getCategoryBooks(this.props.match.params.id);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { categoryBooks } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {/* <h1>{this.props.match.params.id}</h1> */}
                {categoryBooks &&
                    categoryBooks.map(book => {
                        return <div key={book.id}>{book.title}</div>;
                    })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapState = state => ({
    categories: state.categories.categories,
    categoryBooks: state.books.categoryBooks
});

const mapActions = {
    getCategoryBooks
};

export default connect(
    mapState,
    mapActions
)(Category);
```

Now, everything is working the first time, however, when I click on another category the `<Category />` component doesn't get updated because I'm dispatching the action in the `componentDidMount()` thus the component already mounted the first time, so it doesn't dispatch the action again after I click on another category, now what is the best way to handle this?

The second issue is where I'm on a category route `http://localhost:3000/category/9967c77a-1da5-4d69-b6a9-014ca20abd61` and I try to refresh the page, the categoris list loads fine on the sidebar, but the single  component shows empty, and when I look on the redux-devtools I find that the `GET_CATEGORY_BOOKS` action gets fired before the `LOAD_BOOKS` and `LOAD_CATEGORIES` in the `App.js` file, because the child `componentDidMount()` method gets called before its parent equivalent method. How to solve this as well?

I hope you guys can help me in this.

## Edit

As @@NguyễnThanhTú noticed, the componentDidupate had a typo, now it works when clicking on another category.
That leaves us with the second issue when reloading the page in the category route and the data doesn't show because of the App.js componentDidMount fires after its children components.

## Edit

Here's a repo on Github for this project ...
https://github.com/Shaker-Hamdi/books-app

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú You're right it was a typo, now it works every time I click on a category, the component did update with the new list of books, thanks for that. Now is that the right thing I'm doing there? calling the action twice? once in `componentDidMount` and again in `componentDidUpate`? I'm just asking.

And also that leaves us with the second issue, when refreshing the page and the child `componentDidMount` fies before its parent.

Comment: could you make this simple app available on GitHub? I'll try to fix it and let you know when it's done

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú Here you go ... https://github.com/Shaker-Hamdi/books-app

Comment: You've got way too much irrelevant code and information in your question. Also, you should post all relevant code directly in your answer following SO forum guidelines. The answer below seems to be based on code from a github link in your comment above.

Comment: @twils0, dude, not just because you didn't get the question you trash it. be cool.

Comment: @Ruby It’s definitely related. I was about to explain my answer in more detail, after I received your comments. I then realized your accept answer was based on code from a link and that your question was all over the place.

Comment: If you clean up the answer, future readers will definitely benefit and, I’ll have no reason to down-vote (i.e. I’ll remove the down-vote).

Comment: @twils0 my question was highly detailed and I provided the repo to clarify more info, and my problem was specific and I was very clear about what my issues were, that's why "NguyễnThanhTú" got the question and was able to help me. I provided step by step code with explanation. So please be classy man. I downvoted your answer because it was simply not what I was looking for. I'm here to learn my friend, so I won't get into any arguments with you or anyone else. Cheers.

Comment: @Ruby you're bringing up a separate issue. You should not down-vote an answer simply because it's not your accepted answer. There was nothing wrong or inherently incorrect with what I said. In fact, you could have used status fields to test when you should getCategoryBooks (i.e. if status === 'IDLE' this.props.getCategoryBooks(..)).

Comment: @Ruby I literally cannot remove the down-vote, unless you edit it. SO won't allow me. Also, please review [question best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Quotes: "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem." You had to link to a Github repo with your entire codebase to get an answer. The answer uses code from the repo. How is that going to help someone in the future, when the repo changes or is taken down?

Comment: @twils0 dude, remove it or not I simply don't care. This conversation is pointless. Bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `booksActions.js`, add this:

```
export const getCategoryBooksV2 = categoryId => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        const { books } = getState();
        if (books.books.length === 0) {
            console.log('Only executing once')  // testing purpose only
            const response = await axios.get("books.json");
            const data = response.data.books;
            dispatch(loadBooks(data));
            dispatch(getCategoryBooks(categoryId));
        }
        dispatch(getCategoryBooks(categoryId));
    };
};
```

In your `Category.js`, use that new action creator:

```
import { getCategoryBooksV2 } from "../books/booksActions";
...
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCategoryBooksV2(this.props.match.params.id);
}
...
const mapActions = {
    getCategoryBooksV2
};
```

This solution is inspired by this example:

```
function incrementIfOdd() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { counter } = getState();

    if (counter % 2 === 0) {
      return;
    }

    dispatch(increment());
  };
}
```

From the [Redux-Thunk Documentation](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#motivation)

This is the demo:

[image]